# Xcode SwiftUI Sharing custom image is blank

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to allow my user to share an image with an overlay via text or social media.

I am successfully creating an image (I know because it shows up in the photos album) using the following extension:

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

When I ‘share’, it acknowledges the image is there (the share sheet changes its options) but the image is either not there or it is an empty white square.

I call it like this:

```
let myImage = textView.snapshot() //uses the snapshot extension above
ShareSheet(activityItems: ["my app name", myImage])

struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
    
    let activityItems: [Any]
    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil ///[.postToFacebook]   //nil
    let callback: Callback? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: activityItems,
            applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
        return controller
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for how myImage gets set? Ideally a [mre]?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Does the edit make it clearer above?  let myImage = textView.snapshot()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not an answer, but since the comments are very limited,
I'm posting some code that may help find why it does not work for you.
For me it seems work, on macos 12.beta5, xcode 13.beta5, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. This is the code I used in my test:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shareIt = false
    @State var myImage = UIImage(systemName: "globe")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Image(uiImage: myImage!).resizable().frame(width: 222, height: 222)
            Button(action: {
                myImage = snapshot()
                shareIt = true
            }) {
                Text("Click to share")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $shareIt, onDismiss: {shareIt = false}) {
                ShareSheet(activityItems: [myImage as Any])
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}

struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
    
    let activityItems: [Any]
    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil ///[.postToFacebook]   //nil
    let callback: Callback? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: activityItems,
            applicationActivities: applicationActivities)

        controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) { }
}
```